# FragmentActivity causing activity leaks (IntentReceiver) but not on MapActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-viewpager, android-mapview

I've developed an application that displays a `MapView` on the main activity (MapActivity) and this mapview contain overlays which when tapped open a pop-up like window with `ViewPager` and fragments inside. I've successfully implemented this by calling another activity using `FragmentActivity` on the pop-up with viewpager but it pauses my `MapActivity` which I do not want. However, this solution does not cause `IntentReceiver leaks`.

My other solution was to change `MapActivity` to `FragmentActivity`, and calling the pop-up with viewpager works very well. However, when closing the activity triggers the `IntentReceiver leaks`. Googling around, and found that the solution to this includes unregistering intent receivers on `onDestroy` method but I didn't register any.

The leaks are `NetworkConnectivityListener$ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver` & `maps.FSTileCache`. I'm using mapquest library by the way. And I'm using compatibility libraries also.

Here's the code:

**Using MapActivity**

```
public class MyMapActivity extends MapActivity {

public MapView mapView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.my_map_activity); 
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.my_map);
        showAllAvailableOverlays();
}

private void showAllAvailableOverlays() {

    Bitmap trafficBitmap = null; 
    List<TrafficProfileDummyModel> dummyTrafficProfiles = new TrafficProfileMockDataSource().getTrafficProfiles();

    for(TrafficProfileDummyModel dtp : dummyTrafficProfiles) {

        View trafficProfileView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.traffic_profile_custom_overlay_item, null);
        ImageView trafficProfileImageView = (ImageView) trafficProfileView.findViewById(R.id.traffic_profile_image_overlay);
        TextView trafficProfileCurrentText = (TextView) trafficProfileView.findViewById(R.id.traffic_profile_custom_overlay_item_currentspeed);
        TextView trafficProfileAverageText = (TextView) trafficProfileView.findViewById(R.id.traffic_profile_custom_overlay_item_averagespeed);

        int curr = (int)Math.round(MyMapActivity.this.currentTripDataModel.getCurrentAverageSpeed()), ave = Integer.parseInt(dtp.getTrafficProfileHistorical()); 

        trafficProfileCurrentText.setText(String.format("%02d",curr));
        trafficProfileAverageText.setText(String.format("%02d",ave));

        Drawable trafficProfileMarkerOverlay = null;
        trafficBitmap=null;
        final GeoPoint geopoint = dtp.getGeopoint(); 

        if((int)Math.round(MyMapActivity.this.currentTripDataModel.getCurrentAverageSpeed()) >= 0 && (int)Math.round(MyMapActivity.this.currentTripDataModel.getCurrentAverageSpeed()) < 35 ) {
            // set marker color to red
            trafficProfileImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.traffic_profile_red));
            //trafficProfileImageView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.traffic_profile_red));
            trafficBitmap = bitmapScalerAndResizer.createDrawableFromView(MyMapActivity.this, trafficProfileView);
            trafficProfileMarkerOverlay = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),trafficBitmap);

        } else if ((int)Math.round(MyMapActivity.this.currentTripDataModel.getCurrentAverageSpeed()) >= 35 && (int)Math.round(MyMapActivity.this.currentTripDataModel.getCurrentAverageSpeed()) < 49) {
            // set marker color to yellow
            trafficProfileImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.traffic_profile_yel));
            trafficBitmap = bitmapScalerAndResizer.createDrawableFromView(MyMapActivity.this, trafficProfileView);
            trafficProfileMarkerOverlay = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),trafficBitmap);

        } else if ((int)Math.round(MyMapActivity.this.currentTripDataModel.getCurrentAverageSpeed()) >= 50) {
            // set marker color to green
            trafficProfileImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.traffic_profile_green));
            trafficBitmap = bitmapScalerAndResizer.createDrawableFromView(MyMapActivity.this, trafficProfileView);
            trafficProfileMarkerOverlay = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),trafficBitmap);

        } 

        final DefaultItemizedOverlay overlay = new DefaultItemizedOverlay(trafficProfileMarkerOverlay);

        final OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(geopoint, "", "");      
        overlay.addItem(overlayItem);

        overlay.setTapListener(new ItemizedOverlay.OverlayTapListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTap(GeoPoint pt, MapView mapView) {

                // this pauses the  current activity    but doesn't produce intent receiver leaks on activity finish()  
                Intent trafficProfileIntent = new Intent(MyMapActivity.this, TrafficProfilePopUpActivity.class);
                startActivity(trafficProfileIntent);
            }


        });

        mapView.getOverlays().add(overlay);
    }

    trafficBitmap.recycle();
    mapView.invalidate();   
 }
}
```

**TrafficProfilePopUpActivity (the popup window with viewpager & fragments)**

```
public class TrafficProfilePopUpActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    params.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;  
    params.x = 0; params.y = -200;
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);
    setContentView(R.layout.traffic_profile_viewpager_prompt_layout);

    TrafficProfilePagerAdapter pageAdapter = new TrafficProfilePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getFragments());
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

    CirclePageIndicator circlePageIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerIndicator);
    circlePageIndicator.setViewPager(pager,0);
}

private List<Fragment> getFragments(){
    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    fList.add(new TrafficProfile_9am_Fragment());
    fList.add(new TrafficProfile_12pm_Fragment());
    fList.add(new TrafficProfile_3pm_Fragment());
    fList.add(new TrafficProfile_6pm_Fragment());
    fList.add(new TrafficProfile_9pm_Fragment());
    return fList;
    }
}
```

---

**Using FragmentActivity**

```
public class MyMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public MapView mapView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.my_map_activity); 
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.my_map);
        showAllAvailableOverlays();
}

private void showAllAvailableOverlays() {

    Bitmap trafficBitmap = null; 
    List<TrafficProfileDummyModel> dummyTrafficProfiles = new TrafficProfileMockDataSource().getTrafficProfiles();

    for(TrafficProfileDummyModel dtp : dummyTrafficProfiles) {

        View trafficProfileView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.traffic_profile_custom_overlay_item, null);
        ImageView trafficProfileImageView = (ImageView) trafficProfileView.findViewById(R.id.traffic_profile_image_overlay);
        TextView trafficProfileCurrentText = (TextView) trafficProfileView.findViewById(R.id.traffic_profile_custom_overlay_item_currentspeed);
        TextView trafficProfileAverageText = (TextView) trafficProfileView.findViewById(R.id.traffic_profile_custom_overlay_item_averagespeed);

        int curr = (int)Math.round(MyMapActivity.this.currentTripDataModel.getCurrentAverageSpeed()), ave = Integer.parseInt(dtp.getTrafficProfileHistorical()); 

        trafficProfileCurrentText.setText(String.format("%02d",curr));
        trafficProfileAverageText.setText(String.format("%02d",ave));

        Drawable trafficProfileMarkerOverlay = null;
        trafficBitmap=null;
        final GeoPoint geopoint = dtp.getGeopoint();

        if((int)Math.round(MyMapActivity.this.currentTripDataModel.getCurrentAverageSpeed()) >= 0 && (int)Math.round(MyMapActivity.this.currentTripDataModel.getCurrentAverageSpeed()) < 35 ) {
            // set marker color to red
            trafficProfileImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.traffic_profile_red));
            //trafficProfileImageView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.traffic_profile_red));
            trafficBitmap = bitmapScalerAndResizer.createDrawableFromView(MyMapActivity.this, trafficProfileView);
            trafficProfileMarkerOverlay = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),trafficBitmap);

        } else if ((int)Math.round(MyMapActivity.this.currentTripDataModel.getCurrentAverageSpeed()) >= 35 && (int)Math.round(MyMapActivity.this.currentTripDataModel.getCurrentAverageSpeed()) < 49) {
            // set marker color to yellow
            trafficProfileImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.traffic_profile_yel));
            trafficBitmap = bitmapScalerAndResizer.createDrawableFromView(MyMapActivity.this, trafficProfileView);
            trafficProfileMarkerOverlay = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),trafficBitmap);

        } else if ((int)Math.round(MyMapActivity.this.currentTripDataModel.getCurrentAverageSpeed()) >= 50) {
            // set marker color to green
            trafficProfileImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.traffic_profile_green));
            trafficBitmap = bitmapScalerAndResizer.createDrawableFromView(MyMapActivity.this, trafficProfileView);
            trafficProfileMarkerOverlay = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),trafficBitmap);

        } 

        final DefaultItemizedOverlay overlay = new DefaultItemizedOverlay(trafficProfileMarkerOverlay);

        final OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(geopoint, "", "");      
        overlay.addItem(overlayItem);

        overlay.setTapListener(new ItemizedOverlay.OverlayTapListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTap(GeoPoint pt, MapView mapView) {

                // this does not pauses the current activity    but when activity closes/finish, produces the intentreceiver leaks              
                final TrafficProfileDialogFragment trafficProfileDialog = new TrafficProfileDialogFragment();
            trafficProfileDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"");
            }


        });

        mapView.getOverlays().add(overlay);
    }

    trafficBitmap.recycle();
    mapView.invalidate();   
 }
}
```

**TrafficProfileDialogFragment (the popup-like dialog with viewpager & fragments inside)**

```
public class TrafficProfileDialogFragment extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {

 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 @Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View trafficProfileDialogFragment = this.onCreateView(getActivity().getLayoutInflater(), null, savedInstanceState);
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogCustomTheme);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();  
    lp.dimAmount=0.90f; // Dim level. 0.0 - no dim, 1.0 - completely opaque
    lp.y = 75;
    lp.height = 300;
    lp.width = 300;
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.TOP);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());     
    dialog.setContentView(trafficProfileDialogFragment);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    return dialog;
 }  

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    }

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View trafficProfileDialogFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.traffic_profile_viewpager_prompt_layout, container, false);
        TrafficProfilePagerAdapter pageAdapter = new TrafficProfilePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getFragments());
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) trafficProfileDialogFragment.findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

        CirclePageIndicator circlePageIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) trafficProfileDialogFragment.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerIndicator);
        circlePageIndicator.setViewPager(pager,0);
        return trafficProfileDialogFragment;
 }  


 private List<Fragment> getFragments(){
    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    fList.add(new TrafficProfile_9am_Fragment());
    fList.add(new TrafficProfile_12pm_Fragment());
    fList.add(new TrafficProfile_3pm_Fragment());
    fList.add(new TrafficProfile_6pm_Fragment());
    fList.add(new TrafficProfile_9pm_Fragment());    
    return fList;
    }    
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to somehow solved the issue by calling mapView.destroy() on the Activity's onDestroy() method. Many thanks guys.